# Find all the items and fields that have dropdown value not in selection list

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have duplicated the site to create new site.
I am seeing on new site some values in drop down are coming from existing site.
I want to find list of items and fields for which value are coming from old site.
How we can achieve this.

Comment: Hi Aman, welcome to SSE. Is this SXA site ?

Comment: No. Its not SXA Site

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach and update the script accordingly. To compare two Sitecore instances and find duplicate items based on a specific field, you can create a PowerShell script that retrieves items from both sites and compares the values of the chosen field. Here's an example script to get you started:

```
# Site A
$siteAPath = "/sitecore/content/SiteA"
$siteAField = "Title"

# Site B
$siteBPath = "/sitecore/content/SiteB"
$siteBField = "Title"

# Get items from Site A
$siteAItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $siteAPath -Recurse

# Get items from Site B
$siteBItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $siteBPath -Recurse

# Hashtable to store encountered field values in Site A
$siteAFieldValues = @{}

# List to store duplicate items
$duplicateItems = @()

# Populate hashtable for Site A
foreach ($siteAItem in $siteAItems) {
    $fieldValue = $siteAItem[$siteAField]
    $siteAFieldValues[$fieldValue] = $true
}

# Compare with items from Site B
foreach ($siteBItem in $siteBItems) {
    $fieldValue = $siteBItem[$siteBField]

    # Check if the field value already exists in Site A hashtable
    if ($siteAFieldValues.ContainsKey($fieldValue)) {
        # Duplicate found, add to the list
        $duplicateItems += @{
            "SiteAItem" = $siteAFieldValues[$fieldValue]
            "SiteBItem" = $siteBItem
        }
    }
}

# Output the list of duplicate items
$duplicateItems
```

Modify the paths (`$siteAPath` and `$siteBPath`) and fields (`$siteAField` and `$siteBField`) according to your specific Sitecore instances and the field you want to check for duplicates. The script will output a list of items that have duplicate values in the specified field across the two sites.

Hope this helps.